# My junit test is not @Autowiring. What am I missing

Tags: spring-boot, junit4

I am trying to unit test my Spring Boot project in Eclipse. The problem I am having is that my @Autowire s are being ignored.

```
@SpringBootTest
public class ValidateRepositoryTest {
    private static final String CREATE_TBLVALIDATE_SQL_SCRIPT = "scripts/create/validate.sql";
    private static final String DROP_TBLVALIDATE_SQL_SCRIPT = "scripts/drop/validate.sql";

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ValidateRepositoryTest.class);

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbc;

    @Before
    public void before() throws SQLException {
        if (jdbc == null) {
            logger.fatal("jdbc == null in ValidateRepositoryTest.before()");
            return;
        }
        ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(jdbc.getDataSource().getConnection(), new ClassPathResource(CREATE_TBLVALIDATE_SQL_SCRIPT));
    }

    @After
    public void after() throws SQLException {
        if (jdbc == null) {
            logger.fatal("jdbc == null in ValidateRepositoryTest.before()");
            return;
        }
        ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(jdbc.getDataSource().getConnection(), new ClassPathResource(DROP_TBLVALIDATE_SQL_SCRIPT));
    }

    @Autowired
    ValidateRepository validateRepository;

    @Test
    public void testFindByKeyCode() {
        if (jdbc == null) {
            logger.fatal("validateRepository == null in ValidateRepositoryTest.testFindByKeyCode()");
            return;
        }
        String documentTypeKeyCode = Validate.DOCUMENT_TYPE_CLAIMS_APPROVAL;
        String sendMethodKeyCode = Validate.DOCUMENT_SEND_METHOD_EMAIL;
        Validate validate = validateRepository.findByKeyCode(documentTypeKeyCode);
        assertEquals("Shortage Claims Approval POD", validate.getDescription());

    }
}
```

The output.

```
[INFO] Running com.kable.newsstand.batch.shortage_claim_auto_accept.entities.validate.test.ValidateRepositoryTest
09:40:51.029 [main] ERROR com.kable.newsstand.batch.shortage_claim_auto_accept.entities.validate.test.ValidateRepositoryTest - jdbc == null in ValidateRepositoryTest.before()
09:40:51.036 [main] ERROR com.kable.newsstand.batch.shortage_claim_auto_accept.entities.validate.test.ValidateRepositoryTest - validateRepository == null in ValidateRepositoryTest.testFindByKeyCode()
09:40:51.036 [main] ERROR com.kable.newsstand.batch.shortage_claim_auto_accept.entities.validate.test.ValidateRepositoryTest - jdbc == null in ValidateRepositoryTest.after()
```

I think it might have something to do with not having @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) at the top, but if I include this, it tries to run my main application, which throws exceptions because instance variables aren't populated from the environment:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ShortageClaimAutoAccept implements CommandLineRunner {
    
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ShortageClaimAutoAccept.class);
    
    private static String cognosUser;
    private static String cognosPassword;
    private static String smtpHost;
    private static String ftpServer;
    private static String ftpUserName;
    private static String ftpPassword;
    private static String ftpPath;
    
    private static Mailer mailer;
    private static FtpRelativePathUsage ftp;

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    
    @Autowired
    ClaimRepository claimRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    ClaimDetailRepository claimDetailRepository;

    @Autowired
    DocumentControlRepository documentControlRepository;

    @Autowired
    DocumentReportRepository documentReportRepository;

    @Autowired
    ValidateRepository validateRepository;

    private void startClaimAutoAcceptApp() {
        if (smtpHost == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("smtp host is null");
        }
        if (cognosUser == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("cognos user is null");
        }
        if (cognosPassword == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("cognos password is null");
        }
        if (ftpServer == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("ftp host is null");
        }
        if (ftpUserName == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("ftp user is null");
        }
        if (ftpPassword == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("ftp password is null");
        }
        if (ftpPath == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("ftp server base path is null");
        }

        acceptClaimDetailsAndCloseClaims();
        emailPODClaims();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            final Properties props = ApplicationPropertiesProvider.getProperties();
            smtpHost = props.getProperty("SYS_SMTP_HOST");
            cognosUser = props.getProperty("REPORT_RUNNER_USER");
            cognosPassword = props.getProperty("REPORT_RUNNER_PWD");
            ftpServer = props.getProperty("FTP_I_CLAIMSPOD_HOST");
            ftpUserName = props.getProperty("FTP_I_CLAIMSPOD_USRID");
            ftpPassword = props.getProperty("FTP_I_CLAIMSPOD_PWD");
            ftpPath = props.getProperty("FTP_I_CLAIMS_BASE_PATH");
            mailer = new Mailer(smtpHost, "");
            FtpSite ftpSite = new FtpSite(ftpServer, ftpUserName, ftpPassword, ftpPath);
            ftp = new FtpRelativePathUsage(ftpSite);

            SpringApplication.run(ShortageClaimAutoAccept.class, args);
        } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
            logger.fatal(ex);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.fatal("Uncaught exception in the process: \n", ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
        startClaimAutoAcceptApp();
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why it tries to run this, when all I am doing is testing.

Comment: What is the package of your test and what is the config class you define your datasource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing two things here:

1. A runner

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
```

2. The component classes to use for loading an ApplicationContext. Can also
   be specified using **@ContextConfiguration(classes=...)**. If no
   explicit classes are defined the test will look for nested Configuration
   classes, before falling back to a SpringBootConfiguration search.

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = ShortageClaimAutoAccept.class)
```